# Vba error: forming table in words after the paragraphs

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to form a table at the word documents after inserting the exceltable as paragraphs.

This is the code that I used.

```
Sub MSWord()
Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document
Dim wTable As Word.Table
Dim wb As Workbook, wsh As Worksheet, i As Long
Dim cel As Cell
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim wRange As Range

Set wApp = CreateObject("word.application")
    wApp.Visible = True
    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.add
    Set tbRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Terms and conditions-Zero Call").Range("A1:A12")
    tbRange.Copy
    wDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    wDoc.Range.InsertAfter vbNewLine
    wDoc.Paragraphs(25).Range.InlineShapes.AddHorizontalLineStandard
    Set tbRange1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Payoff-Zero Call").Range("A1:F32")
    tbRange1.Copy
    wDoc.Paragraphs(26).Range.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    intNoofRows = Year(Worksheets("Input").Range("H5")) - Year(Worksheets("Input").Range("G5"))
    intNoofColumns = 4
    Set wRange = wDoc.Range
    wDoc.Tables.add wRange, intNoofRows, intNoofColumns
    Set wTable = wDoc.Tables(1)
    wTable.Borders.Enable = True
    wTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "j"
    wTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Optional Redemption Date"
    wTable.Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = "Optional Redemption Amount"
    wTable.Cell(1, 4).Range.Text = "Optional Redomption Price"
    For i = 2 To intNoofRows
        wTable.Cell(i, 1).Range.Text = i - 1
        wTable.Cell(i, 2).Formula ("=Date(Year('Payoff-Zero Call'!$C$22)+i-1,Month('Payoff-Zero Call'!$C$22),Day('Payoff-Zero Call'!$C$22))")
        wTable.Cell(i, 3).Formula ("=Input!$D$5 & Round((1000000*(1+100*Input!$I$5/100)^(i-1)),2)")
        wTable.Cell(i, 4).Formula ("=ROUND((1000000*(1+100*Input!$I$5/100)^(i-1)),2)/1000000")
    Next i
```

Just ignore the contents of the table, they just the output of the formula that I entered. ALso, the previous part about the pasteExcelTable you can also ignore it. I just posted it because it might give a better idea on what i really want. So I would want the formed table in the word to be put right after the pasted excel table which refers to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Payoff-Zero Call").Range("A1:F32")`

The problem is, at the For loop, I keep on getting the error: Application defined or object defined error. Or sometimes Type Mismatch when I try to adjust some trivial details.

Maybe is there my misconception in inserting table after the excel paste paragraph? Because if I just separate the tables code from previous code to only form table in the blank word, there is no problem.

Could you please shed some light for this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it the last line in the loop cause you're missing a `"` at the end?

Comment: My bad. This is just a mistake. It's not the reason for error. The error occurs at the first part of the formula.